# Magento 2 - How to remove phone number validation in adminhtml

Tags: magento2.2, adminhtml, form-validation

Magento 2 I want to remove phone number validation in customer addresses in admin panel

**--- Screenshot for your reference ----**

[image]

Comment: There is no phone validation in magento 2 admin, however phone number is required. You want to make the phone number optional?

Comment: Frontend phone number validation option is in admin panel but admin phone number validation is done it in UI component